# JavaMail Messaging Exception

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I wrote a program to send gmails using JavaMail API. Following is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.activation.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;

class emailSend{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String recipient = "receiver@gmail.com";
        String sender = "sender@gmail.com";
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host",host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", sender);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", "password");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

        try
        {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient));
            message.setSubject("This is the subject");
            message.setText("This the message");
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com",465,"sender01@gmail.com", "password");
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            System.out.println("Mail successfully sent");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting following error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2197)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:740)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
at emailSend.main(emailSend.java:29)
```

I tried disabling the firewall, but it was of no use.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Add properties:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your Gmail account security to allow it to send emails from your app [check the link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/)

This is my working code

```
      Properties props = new Properties();    
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");    
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");    
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",     "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");    
      props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); 

      //get Session   
       Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,    
       new javax.mail.Authenticator() {    
       protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {    
       return new PasswordAuthentication( from, password);  
       }    
      });    

      //compose message    
        try {    
       MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);    
       message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(recepient));    
       message.setSubject(subject); 

       BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
       messageBodyPart.setContent(msg, "text/html");
       Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
       multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
       messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
       DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
       messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
       messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
       multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
       message.setContent(multipart); 
       Transport.send(message);  

      } catch (MessagingException e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);}
```